# Cascade connection of TS3USB221 USB multiplexers

Tags: usb, transmission-line

I need to design some kind of selector logic in order to route USB signals to three different selectable sinks. For this purpose I decided to use TS3USB221 1:2 USB multiplexer from TI. It turned out that I need 3 levels of TS3USB221 connected in series. The datasheet of the TS3USB221 is available here: [TS3USB221 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts3usb221.pdf)

Initially I do not understand different ON resistance values such as ON_state resistance, ON-state resistance match between channels and ON-state resistance flatness. 
I also do not understand input (ON) capacitance. Is it between D+ and D- or between each of them and GND.
Without understanding this I am not really able to derive the equivalent electrical circuit of the trace when using 3 stage multiplexer.

The second question is how does multiplexer influence reflections on USB trace. We are using USB 2.0, and I USB traces are shorter than 5cm, so maybe the transmission line effects are still negligible  (?).

Here is the frequency response of the TS3USB221:
[image: TS3USB221 Frequency Response]

As can be seen, by putting three of this devices in series, -3db point will be moved from about 650 MHz to about 400 MHz.

How could I combine all of the available data in order to be able to say if this is going to work.

Thanx!

Comment: Why do you need to put three devices in series? You only need two to make a 3:1 switch.

Comment: And capacitance is measured for each input pin on its own; see Figure 14 on page 11 of the datasheet.

Comment: I need three levels of multiplexing because of some backward compatibility.

Comment: Which mode of USB signaling you are working with FS? HS?

Comment: It's High-speed signaling.